# Voltage convert from 110v to 220v

Tags: soldering, reverse-engineering

Should the ceramic heater in soldering iron be changed to convert the iron from 110 volt to 220 volt? What about the Thyristor?

I know getting new iron is better, but my question is just for learning. 
Thank you

Comment: Change nothing, just get a suitable autotransformer. The iron will work in specs and you wont have to mess with it.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

For a "simple" iron, where the heating element is directly connected to the AC line, you would need to change the heating element to operate on a different voltage.

For a modern temperature-controlled iron, the heating element likely operates from a low voltage, so you would have to change the power upply/temperature controller.

In either case, the easiest solution is to buy a new iron designed to operate from the available voltage.

Comment: Thank you Peter. Sure, buying new is easier. My question was just for understanding :)